# How to abort a particular task in bull queue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, message-queue, priority-queue, job-queue

According to this package https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull is it possible, to abort a certain task in the "waiting queue"?
My use-case is as follows:

I have a mongodb collection "users" and a collection "friendship" where I store name and avatar of both users. So I only need one query to get friendlist of a certain user. When a user changes his avatar, I have to update all documents within this user in "friendship" collection. This is a performance-uncritical operation since I want it to do in background and consistency is not important for this use-case. But when a User updates his avatar several times in a short time span, I want to  cancel all referencing old tasks (for updating the friendship collection) except the newest. Is this with bull possible?

Thanks in advance, I would appreciate every information about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the Bull reference you will find that there is a `Job.remove()` method. Since you haven't posted any code I could only guess how it looks like. Hence I have described what you could do.

However what you have to do is to store the `Promise<Job>` which will be returned by `Queue.add()` for instance in a `Map<string, Map<string, Promise<Job>>`. String would be the `_id` of your user and `Promise<Job>[]` is an array containing all the queued jobs for a specific user. Once a Job has been resolved (you can await the resolved job with `Job.finished()`) you need to remove the Promise from your Map.

Whenever a user changes his avatar you could then look into your Map if you need to remove any jobs. The value in the above mentioned Map is another Map (key is a string, which represents the `JobId`) which easily allows you to remove Jobs by JobId. That may sound a bit complex, but don't be afraid - if you understand how Maps work it shouldn't be a problem :-).

Comment: @kentor can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56256609/bull-queue-is-not-getting-completed ?